# Blank screen with blinking cursor when trying to boot

Tags: black-screen

I accidentally changed permissions on /var folder on my os when trying to set up apache. 
Afterwards trying to turn my computer back on it shows the elementary logo then sends me to a black screen with blinking cursor. The screen seems to be stuck can't do anything. CTR ALT DEL sends me back to elementary logo then boots windows

I have tried changing permissions to default without any luck. Also tried to boot on different  linux generics on recovery mode.

Been stuck on this for days any help would be appreciated.

Aplology in advance for this not being detailed enough. Don't know much abt os